# SQL, Transform rows to columns with math

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this table:

```
Player    Routes   Colors

 GIN         2      RED    
 GIN         1      BLU    
 GIN         5      BLAS    
 GIN         1      TREN    
 GIN         2      RED    
 PON         1      TREN
 PON         4      BLU
```

from a query with union all, like this:

```
select *
from (
        select  DISTINCT Colors.Name [Colors]
              , COUNT(routes.idRoutes) [Routes]
              , Routes.cdRoutes [Doc]
        from Routes
        inner join Colors on Colors.Name blablabla
        where blablabla
        group by Colors.Name, Routes.cdRoutes

    ) dates
```

I need to have a table like this instead:

```
Colors    GIN    PON

 RED       4      0 
 BLU       1      4
 BLAS      5      0
 TREN      1      1
```

How to? I think I can obtain it without using PIVOT function, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this (even without using of PIVOT):

```
select
    Colors,
    sum(case when Player = 'GIN' then Routes else 0 end) as GIN,
    sum(case when Player = 'PON' then Routes else 0 end) as PON
from your_query_or_Table
group by Colors
```

Comment: Dear Andy, Your script is beautiful, except that I need the count of "Routes.idRoutes". How to? I receive this error: Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

Comment: @JohnSam wait.... you've selected `COUNT(routes.idRoutes)` as `Routes` in your query. It is supposed that my query is using result of your original one - so it just sums Routes which is count of isRoutes by definition of your query. You should change `your_query_or_Table` from my query to your query text itself